# Sheet add-on stopped loading after project document was undeleted

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way I can reach out to someone in the Google Apps team who could help me with an outage?
I accidentally deleted the file that contained the project associated with a Sheets Addon published on the web and having 5000+ users (had a thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704711/i-accidentally-deleted-the-google-sheet-that-contained-code-for-my-published-add)
I worked with Google Drive support to undelete the file and now I can access it, and all the code is fine.
However, since then the addon installed by so many users stopped working for everyone. It gives the users the following error:
"We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

I tried re-publishing a new version of the add-on, but I can't do that either, I'm getting the following error:
[image: Publish Error]
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Was able to fix this by reassigning the sheets addon code to a different Developers Console Project: Resources -> Developer Console Project... -> Change Project. 
Just created a new empty project for that.
It looks like the problem was in the addon being linked to a project that for some reason got deleted when I deleted the addon code. And restoring the addon code didn't restore the association with the project.
It's still a mistery to me how a Sheets Addon depends on the Developer Console Project, but reassigning it to a different project fixed the issue. I was also able to publish an updated version of the addon, however creation of the new project triggered a manual review, so it'll take some time before new fixes will become available.